# BigQuery create Table differences between standard and legacy sql

Tags: google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I have a few questions around the create table syntax in standard and legacy sql

1. The new BigQueryUI doesn't show standard sql types and shows only legacy types. I understand they are mapped one to one with the legacy types but the examples in creating [partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions#creating_an_empty_partitioned_table_with_a_schema_definition) shows options which are not available in the UI
2. If I create a table using the JSON field schema can I still use the standard sql?
3. The BigQueryUI shows only partitioning the table by Ingestion time, but I want to create a table with date column and I don't see an option for it. If I have to create the DDL manually, I did not see the examples on how to use JSON field schema to construct a create table statement.

Answer (score 1):

> The new BigQueryUI doesn't show standard sql types

BigQuery standardSQL and LegacySQL are 2 options to write SQL syntax (See this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) for more detail) and have nothing to do with the column Types in BigQuery, Details on table types can be found in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables), I also find this [Link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types) helpful

> If I create a table using the JSON field schema can I still use the standard sql?

To create a table using JSON you need to run `bq` [command line](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool), If you need help how to write this syntax let us know

> but I want to create a table with date column and I don't see an option for it

You can use this standardSQL syntax to do this:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project.dataset.tableId`
PARTITION BY myDate
CLUSTER BY cluster_col AS
SELECT * from sourceTable
```

Note: myDate column is a column in the source table

Comment: Thanks Tamir. What if the table I want to create is a brand new one into which I want to stream data? Then it appears I have to create a dummy table with no records and use the query you provided to create the table I want.

Comment: Correct this is the way. If you find my answer helpful for you please consider accepting it and voting up

Comment: @PK109, note: important on SO - you can mark accepted answer by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. See [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235) for why it is important!